# bytestr.decode('utf8') return UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x

read from file a byte string:

```
>>> s = b'------WebKitFormBoundary02jEyE1fNXSRCL7D\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fileobj"; filename="3d15ef5126d4fa6631a863c29c5a741d.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x006Exif\x00\x00II*'
>>> s
b'------WebKitFormBoundary02jEyE1fNXSRCL7D\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fileobj"; filename="3d15ef5126d4fa6631a863c29c5a741d.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x006Exif\x00\x00II*'
>>> print(s.decode('utf8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 167: invalid start byte
```

why UnicodeDecodeError? s.decode('utf8') must return str object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bytestring contains a binary image among other things. `'utf-8'` is a character encoding -- it is used to encode text, not binary data such as images.

In general, to parse MIME data, you could use `email` stdlib package.

In your case, it is enough to find the end of the headers (empty line) and save the rest as image:

```
import cgi

headers, _, image = s.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')
L = [cgi.parse_header(h)[1].get('filename') # parse headers, to get filename
     for h in headers.decode('ascii', 'strict').splitlines()] 
filename = next(filter(None, L))
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not proper `UTF-8` string. `UTF-8` char can't start from `0xff`. You can use a `errors` flag to control decoding process. Read [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Yes, `bytes.decode` and `bytearray.decode` return `str` object.